# How would I find out which is the flattest Center Parcs?

Tags: uk, accessibility

I'd like to take an elderly relative to one of the Center Parcs sites in the UK.  She tires easily going up and down slopes, so I'd like to find out which of the sites is flattest - ideally out of Whinfell and Sherwood Forest, as those are closest to her, but overall is good too.  How would I find out this information?

Comment: Have you tried just calling the company? There are phone numbers listed on the website: https://www.centerparcs.co.uk/contact/telephone-numbers.html

Comment: I can tell you that Longleat is rather hilly, and Woburn surprisingly so given that it's not a massively hilly area.  At Woburn a good choice of accommodation can significantly reduce the amount of hills to tackle

Comment: Also, if you call the company with a more general inquiry about bringing a relative with limited mobility they may be able to offer other information/solutions - e.g. a completely flat site may not be useful if every amenity is a long walk from your accommodation.

Comment: https://www.centerparcs.co.uk/information/accessibility.html

Comment: Frame challenge: Would something that increases her mobility (EG short term rental of a scooter) be a better choice than simply limiting the destinations based on flatness?

Answer (score 8):

The thing is, what you need isn't the total hilliness of the site, but the hills between the bits you want to visit.

OpenStreetMap has really quite detailed mapping (at least for [Woburn](https://www.openstreetmap.org/query?lat=52.0249&lon=-0.5344#map=16/52.0216/-0.5280&layers=Y), which I can remember, it even has the lodge numbers).  With the Cycle Map or CylcOSM layers you get contour lines at 10m intervals, so you can look at a typical lodge and the facilities you might want to get to (or just a stroll round the site), and work out how much climbing there is.  The "Query features" tool will help you identify facilities, though zooming in on the Standard layer might be enough).

The routing engines built into OSM won't route you round the site, but [Komoot](https://www.komoot.com) will (you might need to create a login, you don't need any paid features for just looking).  Apparently it's 360m with 20m of climbing at a maximum gradient of 7% from the Sports Cafe to where I stayed a year ago.  Set to Hiking mode to ignore the one-way system that (doesn't apply to bikes anyway) it will count the climbing for you, and indicate the steepness.

At a quick look, Whinfell might be the hillier site of your top two overall, but perhaps has more accommodation close (horizontally as well as vertically) to the main buildings; these may also be on more of a level with each other (quite a lot is in the sports building so it's not unlikely for someone with limited mobility to want to go there, and not just to watch others).

It's also worth looking into what assistance options there are available, free or to hire.